# Assuming that $f''(a)$ exists, show that: $f''(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Assuming that $f''(a)$ exists, show that:
>   $$f''(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}$$

I got the first derivative by using the limit rule $(f(a+h)-f(a))/h$. But when taking the second derivative, I thought of doing the same thing on $f(a)$ of the equation, but I couldn't reach this answer.

Comment: Do you have Taylor's formula in your toolkit?

Comment: No, I don't have.

Comment: L'Hospital"s rule?

Comment: Yes, I have learned.

Comment: Then, apply it twice.

Comment: @Bernard L'Hopital rule assumes that $f$ is differentiable in some neighbourhood of $a$, and we also need continuity of the second derivative

Comment: The O.P. didn't mention   hypotheses, but if $f$ is twice differentiable at $a$, it must be differentiable in some neighbourhood of $a$.

Comment: @ mfl: All the proofs in that link are wrong.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Because   differentiability at $a$ implies the function (here, the first derivative) is defined in a neighbourhood of $a$. If that is  not satisfied, how do you define the rate of variation and its limit?

Comment: @Bernard Yeah, I meant that $f$ must have a second derivative in some neighbourhood of $a$ to use the L'Hopital rule twice, which we don't know.

Comment: Actually, I meant applying L'Hospital's rule once, then the definition of the second derivative.

Comment: @Bernard After such correction, then your proof is correct and is the same with mine. We need to bear in mind that we cannot use L' Hospital rule twice.

Comment: I believe that I wrote a perfect proof. However, someone gave me a down vote without any reason. I would like to call for justice and ask the moderator to ban this guy.

Comment: @Bernard I don't mean you are the downvoter. I just mean there exists (an unknown) downvoter who downvoted my answer without any justification.

Comment: Downvoting is completely OK, provided that this action is justified. For example, a serious mistake appears in the proof and the downvoter explicitly points it out. Every donwvoting must accompany with a reason.

Answer (score 4):

To be precise, let me re-phrase the question: Let $I$ be an open
interval, $a\in I$, and $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that
$f''(a)$ exists, then 
$$
f''(a)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(a+h)+f(a-h)-2f(a)}{h^{2}}.
$$

Proof: That $f''(a)$ exists implies that there exists $\delta>0$ such
that $f'$ exists on $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ and $f'$ is continuous
at $a$. Define functions $\phi:(0,\delta)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
and $\psi:(0,\delta)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $\phi(t)=f(a+t)+f(a-t)-2f(a)$
and $\psi(t)=t^{2}$. Clearly $\phi$ and $\psi$ are differentiable.
Note that 
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow0+}\frac{\phi(t)}{\psi(t)}
$$
is a $0/0$-indeterminate form. By L'Hospital rule, we have 
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow0+}\frac{\phi(t)}{\psi(t)}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0+}\frac{\phi'(t)}{\psi'(t)},
$$
**provided that the limit on the RHS exists**. But 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{t\rightarrow0+}\frac{\phi'(t)}{\psi'(t)} & = & \lim_{t\rightarrow0+}\frac{f'(a+t)-f'(a-t)}{2t}\\
 & = & \lim_{t\rightarrow0+}\left[\frac{1}{2}\frac{f'(a+t)-f'(a)}{t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{f'(a)-f'(a-t)}{t}\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2}f''(a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)\\
 & = & f''(a).
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, we conclude that 
$$
f''(a)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0+}\frac{f(a+h)+f(a-h)-2f(a)}{h^{2}}.
$$
The case that $h\rightarrow0-$ can be proved similarly.